# What is best Practices to use AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, autolayout, xib

Since iOS7, I have been searching for standard GUI design pattern.

In my previous two apps, I unchecked autolayout and used autosizing.

It usually looks like this

[image]

Main View looks like below in SIZE INSPECTOR.

[image]

Currently I am making two xibs, 
iPhone4
iPhone5
and use UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin & UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin along with -64 in iOS6/7 Delta.

For Inner/Child Views, I usually Keep UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin and UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin and -64 in iOS6/7 Delta to work fine in iOS6.

[image]

It give almost perfect result, but sometime I need to start View from start of xib (0,0) but sometime from (64,0) to show Views look like starting from upper most border of View while running.

It makes me confused a lot to understand what is standard way to design XIB, so that we can use single XIB for iPhone4 and iPhone5 and on both platforms.

Thanks

Comment: Why make to NIBs voor th 3,5" and 4" devices, you could just use the Autosizing mask to make up for the different heights. I've have never ever used to NIBs for 3.5" and 4" devices.

Comment: @rckoenes, iPhone 5 height is bigger than iPhone4. so If a View is of bigger than 480 px, how will u adjust it inside a 3.5" (iPhone5)?

Comment: Set the autoresizing mask to flexible height and no flexible top or bottom.

Comment: Can you show me image of Autosizing, how you put for Main views and for child views?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o823ceqpvj6a95o/Screenshot%202014-02-06%2012.40.07.png) this is how I set all my root view to make sure that they grow or shrink. I'm even using the same NIB for the iPad.

Comment: But this is for both, inner and outer views?
I menas MAIN VIEW and its childs like UIButton, UILabel etc?

Comment: What if my one button is at botton of nib which is Ratina 4 inch, it will not fit to iPhone4, then bottom button will be removed when I change simulator from iPhone4 to iPhone 3.5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46926/discussion-between-veer-and-rckoenes)

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I find that using Interface Builder with AutoLayout is not very user friendly and that it quickly became messy.

I prefer do all AutoLayout stuff programmatically. To avoid lot of boilerplate, I use the [Masonry library](https://github.com/cloudkite/Masonry) which is quite amazing.

Answer (score 0):

As described in apple developer official website, the below link exposes the guidelines of using Visual Format Language for auto layout which one is the best practices adopted among the iOS developers nowadays.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html

Comment: Please try to include a summary of the contents of linked articles, rather than just providing the link. I have just updated your link, as it was broken (see the edit history); but I do not currently have time to go about adding the summary myself.

Answer (score 0):

Writing Auto Layout code from scratch isn't easy.There is similar option available for AutoLayout stuff. We can set all constraints programatically with the help of PureLayout. https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout

**Installation:**

1. Add the pod `PureLayout` to your Podfile.

   ```
   pod 'PureLayout'
   ```
2. Run `pod install` from Terminal, then open your app's `.xcworkspace` file to launch Xcode.
3. Import the `PureLayout.h` umbrella header.

   1. With `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile

      **Swift:** `import PureLayout`

      **Objective-C:** `#import <PureLayout/PureLayout.h>` (or with Modules enabled: `@import PureLayout;`)
   2. Without `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile

      **Swift:** Add `#import "PureLayout.h"` to your bridging header.

      **Objective-C:** `#import "PureLayout.h"`

You are done!. Now make some beautiful design with `PureLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for using auto layout is to practice a lot until you get fluent using it :-(

You can then use several strategies.

The one that isn't going to work and that will make you pull your hair out is trying to combine interface builder and constraints in code. Don't do that.

The second that works after you figured out things is to do everything, design and layout using layout constraints, in interface builder. Note that layout constraints can be IBOutlets and that you can manipulate the constants of layout constraints in code quite easily.

The third that also works is to create your views in code, including the layout constraint. Use or write a library that makes creating constraints easier.